If $R$ is not simply connected, then the conclusion of Dulac's criterion is no longer valid. Find a counterexample.
This is taken from section 7.3 problem 16 of Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz.
If $R$ is not simply connected, then the conclusion of Dulac's criterion is no longer valid. Find a counterexample.
I'm having trouble knowing where to start with this. I'm guessing you want your $\nabla \cdot \dot{x} = x^2 + y^2 - c$ for some constant $c$ and then you pick the annulus (which is not simply connected).
you can try something like
$$\dot{x} = (x^2 + y^2) x - x$$
$$\dot{y} = (x^2 + y^2) y - y$$
but then I'm not sure what the closed orbits of this are.

What is $R?{}{}{}$

It's region the vector field is defined over
